# Docker eclipse-temurin throws error "/bin/sh: 1: [java,: not found"

Tags: java, docker, eclipse-temurin

I have a simple jar file that I am trying to run in a docker. Searching for Java dockers, I found recommendations for `eclipse-temurin` so I decided to use it. I am using docker and not docker-compose.

My Dockerfile is this:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:11
LABEL MAINTAINER="shimons@COMPANY.com"

ENV CONFIG_DIR=/var/config
RUN mkdir -p /var/config
RUN mkdir -p /media/data
RUN mkdir -p /var/feeder
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/feeder

COPY feeder.jar /var/feeder
WORKDIR /var/feeder

CMD ["java", "-jar", "/var/feeder/feeder.jar" "--config-file" "/var/config/application.properties" "&>>" "/var/log/feeder/feeder.log"]
```

(I am not really sure that this "&>>" is okay).

Creation:

```
cd /source/feeder || exit
cp feeder.jar Dockerfile /tmp/feeder
cd /tmp/feeder
docker build -t feeder .
```

The image is created with no problems. I run it:

```
docker run -d -v /media/data:/media/data -v /var/config:/var/config -v /var/log/feeder:/var/log/feeder --name=feeder_$((RANDOM)) feeder
```

It stops immediately. `docker ps -a` gives me a container id, and when I try `docker logs <container_id>` I get `/bin/sh: 1: [java,: not found`.

Everything looks okay to me, but it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that `java` is in the `PATH`? What does `echo $PATH` print within the container?

Comment: In `CMD ["java", "-jar", "/var/feeder/feeder.jar" "--config-file" "/var/config/application.properties" "&>>" "/var/log/feeder/feeder.log"]`, make sure there's a `,` between all components of the command, i.e. `CMD ["java", "-jar", "/var/feeder/feeder.jar", "--config-file", "/var/config/application.properties", "&>>", "/var/log/feeder/feeder.log"]`. However, I don't know whether output redirection and similar shell builtins like `&>>`work with `CMD` like that. You might need an external script for that (which you add to the docker image and call from the `CMD` command)

Comment: Thanks a lot @dan1st. I missed some commas there! Stupid. Worked for 2 hours and didn't see it.

Comment: @MCEmperor, inside the eclipse-temurin there should not be a problem with the path. Its whole purpose is to allow me to run java programs. But thank you for trying to help.

Comment: If you're seeing an error of the form `[something,: not found` that usually means your `CMD` doesn't actually have correct JSON syntax; also see [Docker image error: "/bin/sh: 1: [python,: not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32709075/docker-image-error-bin-sh-1-python-not-found).  With JSON-array `CMD` syntax, `&>>` will be passed as an argument to the program.

Comment: @DavidMaze, thank you. Indeed this was the second iteration - after the CMD part worked, the feeder threw an error because it was sent a parameter `&>>` which it did not recognize. But the first problem was actually some missing commas.

Answer (score -1):

`ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","docker-demo-2.jar"]`   commans might missed in entrypoint field between java jar and image name check that and rebuild and push again to docker and then run